Why are Material-UI (MUI) default styles overridden by Tailwind CSS?
I am building a Next js application using both Material-UI (MUI) and Tailwind CSS. However, I’ve noticed that the default Material-UI (MUI) styles are being overridden by Tailwind CSS styles, even though I’ve applied MUI components as shown below.
1.Material-UI Button with Tailwind CSS styles applied (uses ! for important flag to override):
<Button
    variant="contained"
    className="!capitalize !font-semibold !rounded-3xl !px-6 !py-2 !bg-[--primary]"
>
  Sign In
</Button>

2.Button without Tailwind CSS overrides (using StyledEngineProvider injectFirst):
<Button
    variant="contained"
    className="capitalize font-semibold rounded-3xl px-6 py-2 bg-[--primary]"
>
  Sign In
</Button>

3 . Tailwind CSS configuration:
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        background: "var(--background)",
        foreground: "var(--foreground)",
      },
      screens: {
        customMd: "900px",
        xs: "480px",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};

4. Tailwind CSS imports in globals.css:
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

5. Root layout file (with StyledEngineProvider to prioritize MUI styles):
import "./globals.css";
import Layout from "@/app/layouts/main/Layout";
import { tyledEngineProvider } from "@mui/material";


export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
      <html lang="en">
        <body>
          <Layout>{children}</Layout>
        </body>
      </html>
    </StyledEngineProvider>
  );
}

Despite using StyledEngineProvider with the injectFirst prop to make sure MUI's default styles are loaded before Tailwind, I’m still seeing that Tailwind styles are overriding MUI styles, especially with components like the <Button>. I expect MUI styles to take precedence unless explicitly overridden, but it doesn’t seem to work as expected.
I’ve tried using the injectFirst prop for StyledEngineProvider, but the problem persists. I’m also using the ! important flag on Tailwind classes to make sure they apply, but this isn't ideal.
Can someone explain why this is happening and how I can ensure that MUI styles take precedence or at least don't get overridden by Tailwind?
